# Hilbert Transform of compactly supported fucntions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am reading the following from Tao: [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes4.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247a.1.06f/notes4.pdf) ;

On page 5, it says observe that if $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $y$ lies outside of the support of $f$, then
$$
Hf(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\pi (y-x)} f(x)dx
$$

I am not sure how to rigorously justify this statement, and in particular how to take advantage of the compact support in order to use something like DCT/MCT. In addition, does this holds true for general $L^p$ spaces?

Comment: The condition $y$ lies outside the support of $f$ guarantee that the integrand do not have any singular point, that's the point.

Comment: you know $1/x$ is not integrable on $\Bbb{R}$ has two reason, (1) the tail decay too slow, the compact support condition eliminate this problem, (2) the singular point at origin makes it not integrable, $y$ lies outside the support $f$ eliminate this problem.

Comment: @yili I got your point, but does this statement holds true for $L^p$, where $1 \leq p \leq \infty$

Comment: $L^2$ is special here, as Fourier transformation works well in this space. To let the expression in the question makes sense, you can simply treat $f$ as an indicator function $1_K$ with $K$ the compact set. Then you see there is no difference between $1\le p\le \infty$

Comment: @yili: Why does $y$ being outside the support eliminate the singularity issue?

Comment: As $x$ range in $\text{supp}(y)$, there is a strict distance between $x$ and $y$, say $|x-y|\ge \delta \ge$, therefore $\frac{1}{|y-x|}\le 1/\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

We can write $f$ as $f= f\cdot\chi_K$,
where $\chi_K$ is the [characteristic function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) for the set $K$, and $K$ is the support of $f$.
Next, we apply some inequality from our toolbox in order to estimate the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\chi_K(x)}{y-x}f(x)dx$$
which I leave to you (but please say if you get stuck).

Also:
Why must $K$ be compact?

Comment: I understand this is bounded and hence well defined, but I don't see why you need $y$ to be outside the support of $f$ with respect to the singularity issue.

Comment: Regarding the last comment, doesn't the compactness of $K$ follow from the definition of the support? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @YZSHAK What did you try?